# How to plot and save multiple Matlab figures in a loop without displaying

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a loop that's producing some data to plot. I tried to apply some of the things suggested in other questions:

```
for i = 1:N
    set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off');
    plot(...);
    saveas(gcf, 'filename.png');
end
```

When I do this, each saved `.png` has the points from the previous plots as well:

[image]

How can I "clear" the points from the previous plots?

Comment: Try `cla` or `clf` before making the next plot.

Comment: `clf` did it, thanks. (Didn't try `cla`)

Comment: @David do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: `hold off` is another valid approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`clf`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clf.html) to clear the contents of the current figure window before plotting the new data.

```
for i=1:N
    clf
    plot(...)
end
```

You can also use [`cla`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cla.html) to clear the contents of the current axes. Generally `clf` will be easier to use in a loop such as this, however `cla` does have it's uses.